# Using Webservice classes in Silverlight when adding service reference instead of web reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, web-services, silverlight-3.0

**Scenario:**

I am using Silverlight 3.0 as client for a web service.

**Design:**

The server has a class named **DeviceInfoService** which has the basic functionality of getting the list of devices, getting the properties of devices etc.

When I open an ASP.NET project and try to add a web reference, I can find an option to add a "Web Reference". After I add the web reference this way, I am able to access the DeviceInfoService class by creating it's object and then accessing it's methods.

**Web Reference v/s Service Reference:**

Coming to Silverlight: when I try to add a service reference, there is no option to add a web reference. Going with Service Reference, everything works fine till WSDL file is downloaded. People say that I can get this option by going back to .NET 2.0, but probably Silverlight won't work in .NET 2.0

**The Problem**

Now when I try to access the class DeviceInfoService , I am not able to find it. All I get is Interfaces -- DeviceInfoServiceSoap and DeviceInfoServiceSoapChannel. Classes named DeviceInfoServiceSoapClient.

The methods GetHostedDevices and GetDeviceInfo are no longer available. All I get is GetDeviceInfoRequest, GetDeviceInfoRequestBody, GetDeviceInfoResponse and GetDeviceInfoResponseBody.

I googled a lot how to use these four classes, only to find nothing. I want to get those 2 classes directly like in ASP.NET and not using those Request Response type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is web reference in ASP.NET is equivalent to service reference in Silverlight.

Here's an example of how to use a web service in Silverlight, e.g. the [CDYNE Profanity Filter](http://www.xmethods.net/ve2/ViewListing.po?key=425930).

Add a new Service Reference to your project, URL is: http://ws.cdyne.com/ProfanityWS/Profanity.asmx?wsdl, leave the name as ServiceReference1.

Use this code behind to call the service (which was implemented to be asynchronous):

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    string badText = "I wonder if the filter will filter this out: shit bad luck";
    ServiceReference1.ProfanitySoapClient client = new ServiceReference1.ProfanitySoapClient();
    client.ProfanityFilterCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference1.ProfanityFilterCompletedEventArgs>(client_ProfanityFilterCompleted);
    client.ProfanityFilterAsync(badText, 0, false);            
}

void client_ProfanityFilterCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.ProfanityFilterCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string cleanText = e.Result.CleanText;  // Web service callback is here
}
```

And you've got a web service up and running in Silverlight!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will surely try it out when am at work and come back. This looks like the probable answer. I was also trying to do something the same, but hardly found any tutorials on the internet even after googling.

Comment: Gergely I have made some changes in project and the project is halfway. Suddenly I find that the constructor takes infinite amount of time to finish. It actually never finished. What can be the problem.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the solution to see which call never executes? Is the client_ProfanityFilterCompleted ever called? Without details or code I can't help much.

Comment: Gergely, I mean I set a breakpoint on the line `ServiceReference1.ProfanitySoapClient client = new ServiceReference1.ProfanitySoapClient();` when I execute that breakpoint, the browser comes in focus. I checked the code. It does not hit the next breakpoint on the next line. Sort of statement execution flow is lost. There is no such big code right now. I am just clicking on a button to execute this piece of code which you gave.

Answer (score 2):

You sound awfully confuse about some concepts.

How about you watch the following Silverlight.Net video and see if that helps? 
[How to Consume WCF and ASP.NET Web Services in Silverlight](http://silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-videos/how-to-consume-wcf-and-aspnet-web-services-in-silverlight/)

Comment: I have started Silverlight, have to consume a web service. The way I used to do traditionally in ASP.NET isn't the same as in Silverlight. This was the reason for the confusion. I was not able to find "Web Reference" when using Silverlight